# test if duration is between a range

Tags: java, date

I have 3 durations

```
// java.time.Duration
var sec1 = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
var sec2 = Duration.ofSeconds(2);
var min1 = Duration.ofMinutes(5);
```

and I want to test if `sec2` is between `sec1` and `min1`. Something like this

```
    if(sec2.between(sec1, min1))
```

does not work.

How can I do that?

**Update - Solution:**

```
// tests if x is within start (inclusive) and end (inclusive)
boolean isBetween(Duration x, Duration start, Duration end) {
    return start.compareTo(x) <= 0 && x.compareTo(end) <= 0;
}
```

Comment: `compareTo(Duration otherDuration)`

Comment: Could you provide some information if you are wanting to use Comparator, have an Object of some kind or what is the result format you have temporal in Duration?

Comment: @April_Nara I only wanting to check if a java.time.Duration is between two other java.time.Durations..nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (sec1.compareTo(sec2) <= 0 && sec2.compareTo(min1) <= 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do as follows:

```
if(sec2.compareTo(sec1)>0  &&  sec2.compareTo(min1)<0)
```

The description of `compareTo` method:

> public int compareTo(Duration otherDuration) Compares this duration to
>   the specified Duration. 
>   The comparison is based on the total length of
>   the durations. It is "consistent with equals", as defined by
>   Comparable. Parameters: otherDuration - the other duration to compare
>   to, not null  Returns: the comparator value, negative if less,
>   positive if greater

Answer (score 0):

To know what you're using the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html the Instant is actually what you are comparing but it also is false if it is negative so you still need to make sure the compiler will not throw an error with your return that doesn't use parens.

```
static boolean isBetween(Duration x, Duration start, Duration end) {
    boolean isBetween = false;
    if(start.compareTo(x) <= 0 && x.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
        isBetween = true;
    } else if(start.compareTo(x) > 0 && x.compareTo(end) > 0) {
        isBetween = false;
    }

    return isBetween;
}
```

The use of Comparator is a best use of the API function to be reusable as again if the function doesn't handle null cases you will get errors.  Try to use the type given then check for criteria. If it's a function you are only using for a specific purpose on one duration the different cases like 0, null and out of the range need to be handled.

```
class DurationComparator implements Comparator<Duration> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Duration o1, Duration o2) {
      int d1 = o1 == null ? 0 : o1.getDuration();
      int d2 = o2 == null ? 0 : o2.getDuration();
      return d2 - d1;
    }
 }
```

This is a better naming for your method still giving you a boolean with the between compare using the Instant. Your solution is only seeing if it not in the range so if you are looking for if it is in between you need to use the compareTo correctly checking both ends of the Duration so this will work.

Comment: I don't understand the code. Why are you returning false for `start.compareTo(x) <= 0 && x.compareTo(end) <= 0`? I want to return true if x is between start and end (start<=x<=end) and you return false. Why?

Comment: A between function is not compareTo and you never specified that until the comment but with this you can see if it is in the range or outside the range and catch if the value is equal to the limits of the range values.